# How do I solve these type mysteries?

Tags: haskell

See these two questions:

```
--I don't want any defaulting. For example, I don't want
--a general Num to convert to Double deep within my codebase.
--I want to keep my codebase as general as possible.
--Only in main, where I actually call my pure functions,
--do I want to specify an actual, concrete type.
default ()

f :: RealFloat a => a
f = undefined

g :: Bool
g = let
        foo :: RealFloat a => a --First question: Why do I even need this?
        foo = f
    in
        foo < 2.0 --Second question: Why is this an error?
```

First, why do I need to explicitly tell Haskell about the type of `foo`? Why can't it automatically deduce it from the type of `f`?

Second, why doesn't `foo < 2` compile? Seems strange because `foo` is known to be `RealFloat` and `2` is `Num`, which is an ancestor of `RealFloat` so I thought `2` would be able to act as a `RealFloat` like it normally can.

I could solve the error by doing `foo :: Double` instead of `foo :: RealFloat a => a`. But you have seen my thoughts on `default ()`. I don't want concrete `Double`s deep within my codebase. I want to keep using `RealFloat` everywhere so I can specify the accuracy I want in `main`. That could be `Float`, `Double`, or even `BigFloat` from the numbers package.

In short, I don't want to specify the computational accuracy deep in my code. The accuracy should remain general and be specified in `main` where I ask Haskell to compute things.

Are there ways out of this situation?

Comment: What compiler error do you get? Include it in your question.

Comment: Suppose I define my own type `A`, with my own `RealFloat` and `Ord` instances. What should the `foo < 2.0` comparison do? Should it call my own definition of `<`, the `Double` one, or something else? It really is ambiguous, as the GHC error should point out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will help understand what's going on if you think of polymorphic values (such as `f` or `foo`) as being *functions* that must be applied to the *type arguments* before any computation can be carried on.

(Indeed, in GHC 8.0, you'll be able to have such type application in the language itself.)

I'll answer your second question first: why is `foo < 2.0` an error? Because `foo` is polymorphic and has to be instantiated at some type in order for the result to be computed. The semantics of `<` depends on such instantiation, and depending on which type you choose, you may get different answers.

So, this works:

```
default ()

f :: RealFloat a => a
f = undefined

g :: Bool
g = let
        foo = f
    in
        foo < (2.0 :: Double)
```

which should answer your first question, "Why do I even need this?" -- you don't.

Now, it looks like you actually want your code polymorphic. For that, you need to let `g` know from the outside which type to use for computation. You ask:

> Why can't it automatically deduce it from the type of f?

Well, it is because `f` is also polymorphic, so *it doesn't know its type itself*! It is also a function from a type to a value of that type. In different parts of your program, it can be instantiated at different types and evaluated to different values.

In order to tell *g* which type to use, you can add a proxy argument like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Proxy

default ()

f :: RealFloat a => a
f = undefined

g :: forall a . RealFloat a => Proxy a -> Bool
g _ = let
        foo = f
    in
        foo < (2.0 :: a)
```

Passing around proxies can be inconvenient. Instead, you can use implicit
parameters:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, ImplicitParams #-}

import Data.Proxy

default ()

f :: RealFloat a => a
f = undefined

g :: forall a . (RealFloat a, ?t :: Proxy a) => Bool
g = let
        foo = f
    in
        foo < (2.0 :: a)
```

This should get you what you're asking; you can say

```
let ?t = Proxy :: Proxy Double
```

in `main`, and the information will get propagated to `g` automatically.

In GHC 8.0, you can replace `Proxy` by enabling `TypeApplications` like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

f :: RealFloat a => a
f = 2.0 - 1e-12

g :: forall a . RealFloat a => Bool
g = let
        foo = f @a
    in
        foo < 2

main = do
  print $ g @Float
  print $ g @Double
```

Comment: That Proxy thing looks too tedious. (1) Can you speak to that idea, versus the idea of doing `type FloatingPointType = Double` and using `FloatingPointType` everywhere in my code? One advantage is that I can replace `Double` with `CReal` in one line of code to increase accuracy. A major drawback is that if I send individual pure functions to other programmers, they'll be burdened with a `FloatingPointType` they are not familiar with. (2) Can you also speak about whether the new GHC 8.0 feature you mentioned can help us solve this in a better way? How would such GHC 8.0 code look?

Comment: (1) the Proxy approach is more flexible in case you don't know in advance which type will be needed (say, you're writing a library that others will use, or the configuration happens at runtime). If you control the whole program, `type FloatingPointType = ...` should suffice. (2) Yes, I added an example to the answer.

Comment: Using implicit arguments is pretty yucky. Another option is to use `ScopedTypeVariables` and manufacture a new proxy whenever you need one and don't happen to have one on hand.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka Thanks, this was great! I'm just going to wait for GHC 8 now. Final question: Do you know of any other programming language that makes this possible? I mean working with ordinary, familiar literals like 2 and 2.0 and functions like exp in such a general way where you can modify the floating-point precision of the whole program by changing just one line! Mind-blowing.

Comment: Hey, caught my last comment? Just checking.

Comment: I haven't thought this through, but it sounds like [type-generic macros](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/tgmath.h.html) in C can do what you want (together with `#define FloatingPointType double`, as in your first comment). That page  mentions that Fortran has such functions, too.

Answer (score 3):

When the function signature does not fully dictate the types of internal values, such as `foo`, you *must* locally inform the compiler about the types of foo and 2.0.  This can be done explicitly via type signatures or implicitly via defaulting and type inference.

Why?  Well there isn't any other mechanism to type `foo` in that expression.  You could provide the machinery yourself if you'd like:

```
import Data.Proxy

g :: RealFloat a => Proxy a -> Bool
g ty = let foo = undefined `asProxyTypeOf` ty
       in foo < 2.0
```

Now the "precision" (as you called it, not exactly an accurate term) is something the callee controls by passing in the correct type:

```
main = print (g (Proxy :: Proxy Float))
```